# How to improve query dependent on multiple rows in another table

Tags: sql, mysql

Given the two tables `a` and `b`, I want to execute a query on `a` which gives the rows that have at least one row in `b` with `b.a_id = a.id` and `flag=1` and at least one row with `b.a_id = a.id` and `flag=0`.

I have a solution for this (see below), but I am wondering if someone knows a more elegant/efficient solution?

The example here is a simplified and distilled version of my real dataset. In reality, table 'a' has millions of rows and there are relevant indexes in place.

```sql
    CREATE table a (
      id int unsigned NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE b (
      id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      a_id int unsigned NOT NULL,
      flag tinyint NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO a VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
    INSERT INTO b (a_id, flag) VALUES
      (1,0),(1,1),(1,1),
      (2,0),(2,1),(2,0),
      (3,1),
      (4,0);
```

select * from a;

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

select * from b;

| id | a_id | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | 4 | 0 |

Expected result of query:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xdUpymCUXDUU6Gmdnku8tS/4)

Current solution:

```sql
    select * from a where
        exists (select * from b where a_id = a.id and flag = 1) 
        and exists (select * from b where a_id = a.id and flag = 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "more elegant", maybe something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/eVuZ6FWw

Comment: `CREATE INDEX idx ON b (a_id, flag);`

Comment: @JonasMetzler I'm thinking it might be bad in my solution to reference the 'b' table twice and there might be a simpler solution. I think you're solution addresses that and I'm going to try it out with my dataset. The groupBy might be a problem when table 'a' consists of a large number of rows.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I have updated my question with information that this is just a simplified version of my real dataset and that relevant indexes are in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify the question we can consider that both 0 & 1 flag should be available in table b for a.id.

**Solution 1**

```sql
select * from a 
where (
  select count(distinct flag) as c 
  from b 
  where b.a_id = a.id and b.flag in (0, 1) #list of flags
) = 2; # count of the unique flags
```

**Solution 2**

```sql
select a.id 
from a 
inner join 
    (
      select b.a_id 
      from b 
      where b.flag in (0,1) 
      group by b.a_id
      having count(distinct b.flag) = 2
    ) as x on x.a_id = a.id
```

or

```sql
select a.id 
from a 
where a.id in 
    (
      select b.a_id 
      from b 
      where b.flag in (0,1) 
      group by b.a_id
      having count(distinct b.flag) = 2
    )
```

The performance of these queries needs to be checked with real data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id from
a,
(select distinct a_id from b where flag=1 ) t1,
(select distinct a_id from b where flag=0 ) t2
where a.id=t1.a_id and  a.id=t2.a_id
```

or

```
select 
a.id
from a,b
where a.id=b.a_id
group by a.id
having sum(case when flag=1 then 1 else 0 end)>0 
and sum(case when flag=0 then 1 else 0 end)>0
```